# simple odata FindEntriesAsync method does not return collection

Tags: xamarin, simple.odata

I'm using Simple.OData.Client library 3.3.0 in my Portable Class library **(PCL)** to retrieve data from my OData v3 service. And i'm sure that my service is working correctly.
When i try to retrieve a collection of Units it returns me  {Simple.OData.Client.ResponseReader}
but not my expected `IEnumarable<IDictionary<string,object>>` collection. Here is th code :

```
    public TajirODataService()
    {
        client = new ODataClient ("http://192.168.0.139/t/tajir3service.svc/");
    }

    public async void InitUnits()
    {
        var units = await client.FindEntriesAsync ("Items_Unit");
        foreach (var item in units) {

        }
    }
```

Please help I'm confused and dont know where to get my collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is strange because ResponseReader is an internal class that should not be exposed to the client. But now that Simple.OData.Client 4.0 is released, I recommend you to upgrade. It has tons of new features (support for V4 and JSON payload) and several bug fixes.

NB! If you are working with iOS application, make sure you have referenced the right adapter, more here: https://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/resolving-filenotfoundexception-when-using-simple-odata-client-in-ios-applications/